# Adding "Excel Table" feature into XML Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, xml

I'm creating an XML file with Excel Spreadsheet 2003 format (I think it's the correct name).

The format is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa140066(v=office.10)

What I'm struggling to do now is to add an "Excel Table".
Since I don't have an excel english version, I'm not too sure about the vocabulary, but what I mean by "Excel Table" is this :

[image]

I tried to find how to do it, but it seem that there is no way ?
Is anyone here know how I can add the "Excel Table" feature into an XML file ?

Bonus question : is the XML Spreadsheet format the correct format for having an "XML Excel" file ?

Comment: What are you really trying to do, using what language? There's no such format any more. `xlsx` files are ZIP packages containing XML files that follow the Open XML standard. While you can work at the ZIP+XML level, there are high level libraries in most languages that allow you to read, generate, modify Excel files at a high level. For example, in C# Epplus allows you to fill a sheet with data from a list, DataTable or even query results with just `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(customers,printHeaders:true)`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The language used for generating the file is "C".
It seem that I'm stuck with this format (my company imposes xml file).

Comment: The single sheet "XML Spreadsheet" format was created as a temporary feature when people started demanding editable, XML-based formats that *didn't* require Excel on a machine. When Microsoft lost a patent for merging XML into Office documents, the decision was made to switch completely to XML  - no merging patents apply when the entire document is XML. The `XML Spreadsheet` format was never meant to be a real spreadsheet format. It was essentially abandoned after 2006 when the XLSX format was published and standardized.

Comment: `(my company imposes xml file` the world imposes `xlsx`. No company can impose an arbitrary format on 5Bn people, the company that actually builds Excel, Google Sheets and Office 365. Except Microsoft, and they imposed `xlsx` 16 years ago. I repeat, again, that `xlsx` is XML packaged in a ZIP file. So if your company wants XML, they only have to use the default format

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't knew any of that, thank a lot !
I will look into that and tell my company that maybe we should use xlsx format.
We use the XML Spreadsheet format for historical reason (it was probably the sole format available at this time).

Comment: If you search in the [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/en/packages.html) package manager you'll find [libxlsxwriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/libxlsxwriter). Table generation is described in [Working with Worksheet Tables](https://libxlsxwriter.github.io/working_with_tables.html). If you use Python, you could use `xlsxwriter` to generate Excel files. Data science libraries like `Pandas` use `xlsxwriter` to save dataframes directly to Excel files, with various degrees of customization